# Currying styled Template Literal function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Im trying to curry the `styled` function but react seems to throwing an error at run time. (JSX element does not have any constructor or call signatures)

The idea is to create a base style that can be reused (without setting the element its attached to).

```
const template = baseStyle`
   backgroundColor: reg
`
const Component1 = template(div)
const Component2 = template(a)
```

The function  accepts an html or styled component. This is what i've done so far, im pretty sure the types are off.

```
export const baseStyle = (strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...rest: Interpolation<any>[]) => {
    return (element: AnyStyledComponent): StyledComponent<any, any, any, any> => {
        return styled(element)(strings, ...rest)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do here is tough because the types for `styled-components` are really complex.  Right now your `element` argument is `AnyStyledComponent` which is an element that's *already* styled.

This type seems to work, but note that styles from the template override those from an already-styled component:

```
export const baseStyle = (
  strings: TemplateStringsArray,
  ...rest: Interpolation<any>[]
) => {
  return <C extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>>(element: C): StyledComponent<C, any, {}, never> => {
    return styled(element)(strings, ...rest);
  };
};
```

You might have better luck using the [`css` utility](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css).

Comment: Thanks Linda, the css is a good alternative that I think i'll have to use for now, in fact this is probably the exact reason for having that. I know it should be possible to get this working. Even in JS, i'm curious if someone has the right solution.